# Stack.PHP does not seem to work on sites that are sub-domains of stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stack.php

The documentation explains to crate objects using the site's url minus the TLD which appears to work fine.

```
$service = new Post_Exchange('gamedev', null, 0);
```

returns what appears to be a valid object (via var_dump):

```
object(Post_Exchange)#1 (9) 
{ 
   ["cache_path"]=> string(6) "cache/" 
   ["_site":"Stack_Base":private]=> string(7) "gamedev" 
   ["_key":"Stack_Base":private]=> NULL 
   ["api_version":protected]=> string(3) "1.0" 
   ["_cache":"Stack_Base":private]=> bool(false) 
   ["_cache_ttl":"Stack_Base":private]=> int(0) 
   ["_current":"Stack_Base":private]=> NULL 
   ["_max":"Stack_Base":private]=> NULL 
   ["last_request":protected]=> NULL 
}
```

but trying to execute a search fails.

```
  $results = $service->question(
     implode(';', $qid), array(
     'answers' => 'true', 
     'body' => 'true', 
     'sort' => 'votes',));
```

Dumping $results gives NULL.

I constantly get the same behavior from sites like CSTheory and Programmers but consistently get expected behavior from Stack Overflow and Server Fault.

Am I missing something obvious or is there a bug?

I'm using version 0.3 downloaded from [pear](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=647).

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of stack.PHP and I'd be glad to answer your question.

The problem is that those sites are actually sub-domains of 'stackexchange.com', so what you need to do is change:

```
$service = new Post_Exchange('gamedev', null, 0);
```

to:

```
$service = new Post_Exchange('gamedev.stackexchange', null, 0);
```

Hopefully you get the expected results. If not please let me know.